# How make channel when bot installed?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want make channel when bot installed.
If new user logined to discord server he should see bot's channel and some message should be sent to that channel.
I tryed like that:

```
client.on("ready", (message) => {
let guild = message.guild;
guild.channels
    .create("nft-checking", { reason: "Needed a cool new channel" })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

But some error is occured in using guild in on ready event.

Comment: The more you look, the more problems you see.

Comment: The `ready` event doesn't return a message object; the `messageCreate` event does.

Comment: Also, please specify the error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a channel, you have a specify the server exactly first like so :

```js
client.guilds.cache.get("id of your server")
.channels.create("test", { type : "GUILD_TEXT", topic : "Some cool channel"})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```